# Download File From MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, upload, download

I can't seem to download my files online which I'm uploading into a MySQL database I only get plain text, vague signs mostly. In localhost though downloading is no problem. I checked my database online and locally both are uploaded good in the upload table. I'll show you Upload.php(It's not called that in real, and this is also not the entire script, It's a big script) first:

```
if (isset($_POST['verstuur'])) {
$id = NULL;
if($_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
}
$query = "INSERT INTO upload (name, size, type, content ) ".
"VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Fout, query mislukt'); 
$query = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() ID";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$id = $row['ID'];
}
```

}

Okay so I have another script where I create the download link:

```
$query = "SELECT U_ID, name FROM upload WHERE U_ID = '$opvraag[U_ID]'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
 echo "<td>Geen Bijlage</td>";
} 
else
{
 while(list($id, $name) = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
     echo '<td><a href="download.php?id='.$opvraag['U_ID'].'">'.$name.'</a></td>';
 }
}
```

And Last I have download.php

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) 
{
$id    = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT name, type, size, content " .
     "FROM upload WHERE U_ID = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Fout, query mislukt');
list($name, $type, $size, $content) =  mysql_fetch_array($result);
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
echo stripslashes($content);
exit;
}
```

The Database Table:
Name:     Type:
U_ID      int(8)              AUTO_INCREMENT
name      varchar(255)
size      int(8)
type      text
content   blob

Comment: Show us your database table

Comment: I suggest you do some debugging first, then tell us where **exactly** your problem is.

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary Database Table Added

Comment: @Jocelyn The exact problem is that I can't download the uploaded files when I click the url where I generate the download link instead it opens up in another webpage

Comment: You said its working in localhost, Have you checked the before setting headers can you var_dump your list variables

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary this is the list var_dump: array(8) { [0]=> string(24) "18085 MEDLON 2012-06.csv" ["name"]=> string(24) "18085 MEDLON 2012-06.csv" [1]=> string(24) "application/vnd.ms-excel" ["type"]=> string(24) "application/vnd.ms-excel" [2]=> string(5) "19628" ["size"]=> string(5) "19628" [3]=> string(19628)

Comment: A huge string is coming(because of uploaded file) but nog 5th array element is coming

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing your 3 calls to `headers()` in your download.php with this:

```
    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
    header("Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
    header("Content-type: $type");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header( "Content-Description: File Transfer");
```

Comment: Didn't Work, altough not online tested it also locally and it worked there.